# Deleting lists upon feature deactivation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have a `FeatureReceiver` class for a feature that deploy a couple of list instances. In the `FeatureDeactivating` event I want to remove those instances as well as other artifacts which get deployed during feature activation (web parts, page layouts and so on).
I have the following piece of code

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating( SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties ) {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges( delegate() {
        SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        bool allowUnsafeUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        web.Lists["_MYLIST__"].Delete();

        web.Update();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
    } );
}
```

This code works very good when I am debugging it and the list get removed as expected. When this code run upon a `stsadm` command the list does not get removed.

I had a suspect about the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` block, which get executed, I think, in another thread, and so I've added a simple `Thread.Sleep(5000)` after that code block.

Now the feature is always removed :O

Because of the fact that the `Sleep` is not properly elegant, can somebody advise a better way to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: What scope does the feature have? If you are able to deactivate the feature than you are already site owner and you don't need to use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: The feature has scope `Web`. I need to use that code block because the deploy on the production servers is not made by me. So I need to get sure that the code will run under the AppPool identity.

Comment: It should run always under the user context. The admin / end user should be able to activate / deactivate the feature. With this you just bypass the built in security system which is not good I think but I might be wrong.

Comment: You don't need to use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to do this - instantiate a new `SPSite` using the `SystemAccount` user token instead. Never use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` if all you work with is SharePoint object model code in the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Delete()` method of SPWeb.Lists

```
    SPWeb webSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    SPList myCustomList = mySite.Lists["MyCustomList"];
    mySite.Lists.Delete(myCustomList.ID);
    mySite.Update();
```

You should also create a new SPSite object while running a code as elevated privileges:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // deletion code goes here...
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I do not have problems with the delete operation.

Comment: You said you were having problem deleting the list using stsadm?

Comment: Oh no. I wrote that the code is working great if I add the sleep. The problem I have encountered is related to the fact that `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedProvileges` runs in another thread which finish after the `FeatureDeactivating` method.